# Netbeans: what is main method?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

I have searched for answers but could not find any relevant answer for me. I tried everything that was answerd(maybe I missed some). I use netbeans 8.0.2 
It always say "main method not found". There is no main class as well. What should I do? Help me. I have reinstalled it also.

Comment: A main method is the entry point into your program. It is required as a start point for your program. Therefore, if it doesnt exist your program will never know where to begin. The main method takes a string array for any arguments passed to it on program start: [see this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the tags you've listed. I'm guessing it's a java question, but please use the correct tags to get better answers. I'd edit it directly, but if it's not Java I don't want to further confuse things. At the very least I'm removing database-connectivity tag

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess this is a Java question, but can be generalised to a lot of other languages.

The main method is, as the name would imply, the main entry point into the program. When the program is run, this is the method that the system (in the case of C), or the Java runtime (in the case of Java) looks for to start running the program.

If the main method doesn't exist then the machine doesn't know where to start the program from and fails with the error that you saw